# Implementing Firm-Wide settings for a Clio App

Tags: clio-api

I am working on a multi-user Clio app that can automatically OCR every document stored in Clio.  I would like to enable my app so that the OCR settings are configured once for the firm and not individually for each user.

How does Clio recommend implementing firm-wide settings?

I had thought about using the @DomainName.com part of the customer's email address but that feels brittle and seems like a good way to create a security issue.

Answer (score 1):

Clio recommends that applications store their application specific settings in their own data store (ie Firebase or similiar would work). If you need to share settings across users in an account you can gain access to the account id via the users end point. The following request (ensure your application has the User Read scope set) should get you started.

```
GET "https://app.clio.com/api/v4/users/who_am_i?fields=id,account\{id\}"
```

This will return something like:

```
{"data":{"id":344855567,"account":{"id":809455327,"redacted":true}}
```

The account id will be the same for each user in the account, you can use this as your account key in storing account specific application settings in whatever data store you're using for your settings.